# How fix "Checking Dart SDK download dart-sdk error in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

i added flutter\bin and dart-sdk\bin to path in windows but when i write create flutter  or type dart or flutter in command line, its show Checking Dart SDK version...
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine a83ed0e5e3b9cd2b5e2f07ef31c72f43c55e93b7... ?

Comment: on first if flutter/dart sdk is not downloaded then any flutter command check the sdk if downloaded or not and if not downloaded it downloads thesdk.. no worries its 1 time only

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me:

- Delete Flutter and Dart folders (ie. the placed you extracted the zip
  file.), as you do that do not delete the zip files.
- Remove Flutter and Dart path from environment variables.
- Extract the zip files again to your desired location.
- Add the .../bin to environmental variables again.

To test:

- go to your terminal and type flutter, wait for the output, followed by Dart.